# jquery selecting all radio buttons ( in list and sublists) excepts the one that certain class

Tags: jquery, css

Please notice this is for an html similar to  this:

```
 <ul>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li class="something"></li>
    </ol>
   <li>
 <ul>
```

I have tried using jquery to select all radio buttons except the one whose parent is the class something, the thing is that the html has lists and sublists, the jquery is as follows:

```
$('.section li:not(.something) :radio').change(function () {
   alert('hello');
});
```

I have created a fiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/p3Enj/

I know I have asked a similar question before the thing is that... I just realized that I didnt shortened properly the html of my previous question.... I am sorry for that...

Comment: if your HTML structure is consistent, you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/p3Enj/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use .not() like

```
$('.section li :radio').not('li.something :radio').change(function () {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5G4z4/)

Comment: my favourite... I am picking this!

Answer (score 4):

Check the parent li elements for the class when doing the change. Try:

```
$('.section :radio').change(function () {
    if($(this).parents('li.something').length == 0)alert('hello');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p3Enj/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

you can check the **class** of `li` in which the radio button is, in the change event using `hasClass()`.

Like this:

```
$('.section li :radio').change(function () {
    if($(this).closest("li").hasClass("something"))
       alert('hello');
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rFWdF/)